# django validate values for calculation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, calculation, django-validation

Hej!

I need to do some simple calculations of filtered data in my django view. This works just fine when having values in the chosen filter. If the value is 0 or None I get an server error and the site collpases. Therefore I need a validator to make sure the given value is not 0 and not None.

(my attempt is at the bottom) Currently if the validator is added it gives me the message that 'float' object is not callable, even before getting to the filter option/template.

And: in my model is a m2m to the model where I get the values from. For each value can a unit be chosen and I only want to calculate if the units are identical, otherwise I want to get a warning.

Does anyone knows how to achieve that?  Or where to look?

Any help is appreciated! :)

```
# validators.py

def validate_values(value):
    if value == 0:
        raise ValidationError(_('One of the given values is 0 or empty and the calculation therefore cannot be proceeded.'),
                              code='notinrange')
```

```
# views.py

def process_mass_intensity(request):
    plants = Plant.objects.all()

    myFilter = PlantsNameFilter(request.GET, queryset=plants)
    plants = myFilter.qs

    total_m = plants.aggregate(Sum('used_in_plant__value'))['used_in_plant__value__sum']

    product_m = plants.aggregate(product_mass=Sum('used_in_plant__value',
                                                  filter=Q(used_in_plant__input_or_output='OUT')))['product_mass'](validators=[validate_values])

    pmi = (total_m / product_m)(validators=[validate_values])

    context = {"plants": plants, "myFilter": myFilter, "total_m": total_m, "product_m": product_m, "pmi": pmi}
    return render(request, 'kpi/process_mass_intensity.html', context)
```

```
# models.py

class Plant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200
    )
    used_xducts = models.ManyToManyField(
        Xduct,
        through="UsedXduct",
        blank=True,
        related_name="used_in_plant"
    )



class UsedXduct(models.Model):
    plant = models.ForeignKey(
        Plant,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="used_in_plant"
    )
    xduct = models.ForeignKey(
        Xduct,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="xduct"
    )
    value = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.ForeignKey(
        Quantity,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    unit = models.ForeignKey(
        Unit,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Validators are applied at the field level.  You can also use [MinValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) instead of a custom validator function here.  Let's break it down.

The reason you're likely getting this error, is because you are multiplying a value (a float, to be specific) times `(validators=[validate_values])`, which is a function.  This doesn't really make sense.

Instead, you would want to put your validators inside your field declaration on your model.  So:

```py
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

class UsedXduct(models.Model):
    plant = models.ForeignKey(
        Plant,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="used_in_plant"
    )
    xduct = models.ForeignKey(
        Xduct,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="xduct",
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
    value = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.ForeignKey(
        Quantity,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
    unit = models.ForeignKey(
        Unit,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
```

Alternatively, to not perform validator on Model creation, you could simply run your validator function in the view itself:

```py
def process_mass_intensity(request):
    plants = Plant.objects.all()

    myFilter = PlantsNameFilter(request.GET, queryset=plants)
    plants = myFilter.qs

    total_m = plants.aggregate(Sum('used_in_plant__value'))['used_in_plant__value__sum']

    product_m = validate_values(plants.aggregate(product_mass=Sum('used_in_plant__value', filter=Q(used_in_plant__input_or_output='OUT')))['product_mass'])

    pmi = validate_values(total_m / product_m)

    context = {"plants": plants, "myFilter": myFilter, "total_m": total_m, "product_m": product_m, "pmi": pmi}
    return render(request, 'kpi/process_mass_intensity.html', context)
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Sadly this isn't working for me. I still get the error that NoneType is not supported. (outside of model) 
Maybe the validator attempt is not working for me here. Do you have another idea how I could achieve that I would get a warning message, that the calculation can't be operated because of a missing value or a mismatched unit instead of a server error?